# SELECT A TABLE FROM A MYSQL DATABASE TO SUBMIT DATA THROUGH A FORM

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am doing a project on a transport management company system that intends to automate most of its operations. the reason I asked the question was that I had an issue trying to map the last phase of the database - finance (3 phases: vehicles, Human resource and finance).

Is there a way I can **choose which table in a database where to submit data using a form**; ***assuming I have three tables, can I use a form to select which table I can store data in to? to be more specific using a drop down list*** e.g ***you have $name, $phone_number, $address and $email so instead of inserting it to just one table let say January_records, you can choose which table to insert into using a drop-down list let say February_records, March_records...etc***

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Of course you can do that. [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Am still in the database design... I thought of it recently but currently I don't know how to implement it...

Comment: @Njay_Stephen So what research have you done? Have you Googled this? Have you tried to write some code?

Comment: @Styphon not yet.. am still in the thought process..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use an select box in the form and in the query do like this

```
<form name="name" method="post">
<select name='tabletoinsert'>
<option value='tbl1'>tbl1</option>
<option value='tbl2'>tbl2</option>
<option value='tbl3'>tbl3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

in php file like this

```
$tbl=$_POST['tabletoinsert'];

$query="insert into '".$tbl."' (col1,col2) values(`val1`, `val2`)";
```

Comment: your welcome but next tym try to show what you have tried or searched to resolve. it will save you from downvote .:)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, Will do.. am sort of new to this... the stackoverflow thing...

Comment: That design will make you very vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @vincebowdren what if I use a framework like codeigniter or laravel?

Comment: @Njay_Stephen Instead of using a framework, I'd recommend redesigning your schema; your january data and february data would be better off if you stored them all in a single _Records_ table.

Comment: @Njay_Stephen. Take a look at http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table for some advice on dynamic table names in sql.

Comment: @vincebowdren thanks... In the part of code that @john posted... Can I have the following: $tbl=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tabletoinsert']);

$query="insert into '".$tbl."' (col1,col2) values(`val1`, `val2`)";

Comment: @Njay_Stephen: That would cut out some of the vulnerabilities, but not all; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string for example.